# Friction Force from Rubber Band

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction

Consider the following problem from the [2022 A F=ma exam](https://aapt.org/physicsteam/upload/2022_Fma_Exam_A-2.pdf):
[image]

The correct answer is A, but the answer I get is off by a factor of 2. The way I did it was to treat the rubber band as a regular polygon with $n$ sides, and then to take the limit as $n$ goes to infinity. Each interior angle has a measure of $\frac{180(n-2)}{n}$ degrees, and thus the friction force that each side contributes is $2T\sin\left(180\frac{n-2}{n}\right) \cdot \mu$. If we multiply this quantity by $n$, we get the total friction force, so we have that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} 2T\sin\left(180\frac{n-2}{n}\right)\mu\cdot n$ is greater than $mg$. Evaulating the limit and solving yields $\frac{mg}{4\pi T}$. What did I do wrong?

Here is a diagram of my work for reference:
[image]